# URL routing, rewrite path but keep mimetype

Tags: asp.net, css, firefox, url-routing

I have implemented my own IRouteHandler for URL routing.
For files without extension it will try to load the filename as a Page from the Pages directory with:

```
return (IHttpHandler) BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(path, typeof(Page));
```

However there are also images and css files (with relative paths) that need to be translated to the correct url. I try to service those files with:

```
try {
   HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(fileName);
} catch (HttpException) {
   throw new HttpException(404, "file not found");
}
```

This works fine (in Internet Explorer), however Firefox is giving me an error:

> Styles.css was not loaded because its
>   MIME type, "text/html", is not
>   "text/css".

Is this caused by the Server.Transfer?
What should I use to redirect the file? Response.Redirect is visible to the client.

Comment: Can't you use Response.Redirect ?

Comment: Response.Redirect is a response header that's sent to the client, therefor instructing the browser to go to a new location. I'd like to keep the redirect 100% server side.

Comment: What happens if you directly load your CSS files from the "right" URL (manually)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, .NET 3.5 and IIS7 introduced a new method: `Server.TransferRequest`.

With the TransferRequest method the request is sent back through the IIS pipeline.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344902.aspx

Firefox is happily accepting my CSS files again.